# Mir gefällt vs ich mag

Tags: pronunciation, grammaticality

I want to say "I am doing this because I like teaching others" and it's not quite clear to me if this should be:

"weil ich die andere zu lehren mag" 
oder

"weil mir gefällt, die andere zu lehren"

Both sound weird to me, sort of unnatural. Am I close to correct with any of the above?

Comment: "lehren" doesn't sound good in this sentence. A German wouldn't use it here.

Comment: _**Die** andere**n** (!)_ is like ***the** others*. You mean just *andere* without article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am doing this because I like teaching others

In this sentence, "Unterrichten" makes more sense than "Lehren". The translation that fits to this sentence in german is like: "Ich mache das, weil ich gerne andere unterrichte".

But you can also say: "Ich mache das, weil ich es **mag**, andere zu unterrichten" or with *gefällt*, then it would sound like that: "Ich mache das, weil mir das Unterrichten **gefällt**".

Comment: thank you very much! On a related note, if I wanted to say "to share from my experience" would then be appropriate to say  "an anderen, aus meiner Erfahrung zu teilen" ?

Comment: I would rather say "Ich will meine Erfahrungen teilen". That means: "I want to share my experience"

Answer (score 4):

try a different one:

"weil ich gerne andere unterrichte"

but also sufficient without "andere"

Comment: ... and also _"Ich mag es (andere) zu unterrichten"_

Answer (score 3):

The word *lehren* is a little bit bulky and as well as the word *unterrichten* rather used in terms of being an actual teacher than just for talking about teaching somebody how to do something.

So in German you would say e.g.

> Ich lehre an einer Hochschule.
>
> Ich unterrichte an einer Grundschule.

If you really want to use *lehren* as in your example, the right sentence would be something like

> Ich mag es, andere etwas zu lehren.
>
> Ich unterrichte gern.

In everyday speech you would rather say something like

> Ich mag es, anderen etwas [beizubringen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/beibringen).
>
> Ich mag es, meinem Hund neue Tricks beizubringen.
>
> Es macht mir Spaß, meiner Nichte das Schwimmen beizubringen.